# Sorting list of lists based on number in inner list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this

```
a = [['abc', 9], ['def', 10], ['ghi', 6]]
```

What would be the shortest way to sort the lists based on the number in the inner lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and `key` argument (The return value of the key function is used for comparison):

```
>>> a = [['abc', 9], ['def', 10], ['ghi', 6]]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1])
[['ghi', 6], ['abc', 9], ['def', 10]]
```

`sorted` returns a new sorted list. If you want to sort the list in-place, use `list.sort` instead.

```
>>> a  # <-- not changed by `sorted` function.
[['abc', 9], ['def', 10], ['ghi', 6]]
>>> a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> a
[['ghi', 6], ['abc', 9], ['def', 10]]
```